# Chardin Js , Hybrid Cordova mobile application - "undefined" is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, undefined

I am trying to create "coach marks"/ instruction overlays in my hybrid mobile app using Jquery and the Chardin.js library : https://github.com/heelhook/chardin.js

But unfortunately I keep getting this error :

**[FATAL] [NONE] Uncaught Exception: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('body').chardinJs('start')') at (compiled_code):5**

this is how my **JS** file looks like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("IN CHARDIN INIT");
$('.container').chardinJs('start');
});
```

And I load all the files in the **HTML** file like this (this code is not showing all the div elements for simplicity):

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet"
href="../../css/jquery/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="../../js/jquery/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chardin/ Coach marks stuff -->
<script src="../../js/chardin/chardinjs.min.js"></script>
<link href="../../js/chardin/chardinjs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Coach marks stuff -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/chardin/chardinInit.js"></script>
</body>
```

Am I doing something wrong here ??

Comment: Try removing `../../` from everything. example `src="js/chardin/chardinInit.js"`

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Doesnt seem like that is NOT the problem as the JS loads right... I can see the console log "IN CHARDIN INIT" fine ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of debugging I found out that the ChardinJs lib was not loading and I had to add it to the body of HTML to load.

The other thing was that Chardin JS has a dependancy that is not mentioned on their website. It  needs the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) plugin that I was missing. As soon as I added this dependancy, It started working.

Comment: Can you tell me what plugin was that and where did you find it please?